# SQL Server: substring leading zero counting is off

Tags: sql-server, casting, substring, zero

I'm trying to make 3 separate fields from a date and now I ran into this problem. When the (DDMMYYYY European style) date is like `04032017`, the code:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST(04032017 AS VARCHAR(38)), 2, 2) AS Month
```

returns `03` (perfect).

But when the code is like (the first zero is now a 1!) :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST(18022017 AS VARCHAR(38)), 2, 2) AS Month
```

the result is 80 because `SUBSTRING` now is counting from the (1) first position and in the first example it took 4 as the starting point.

Obviously I need to have 1 code for all occurrences but I just don't get it right.

Some help would be appreciated!

Regards, J

Comment: Rewrite as `CAST('DDMMYYYY' AS VARCHAR)` a possibility?

Comment: `04032017` is interpreted as an int not a string so is `4032017`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
select SUBSTRING(right('00000000' + CAST(04032017 AS varchar(38)),8), 3, 2) as Month
```

Comment: tested it and this seems to works just fine! Thanks! Just solved it myself in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

You might require to parse this as varchar and then convert into valid date and use month() function to get clear approach

```
declare @date nvarchar(10)='18022017'
select Month(cast(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@date,3,2),'/',SUBSTRING(@date,1,2),'/',SUBSTRING(@date,5,4)) as date))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just solved it. Just remove the cast (why did I use that in the first place?) and put single quotes around the date:

```
select SUBSTRING('04032017'), 2, 2) as Month
```

This works just fine!